# How to display list of languages with their native letters?

Tags: android

I want to convert language codes to their display forms (with their native letters). For example:

Need to convert these language codes :***en, ru, it, ja***

Result should be this list:

***English, Русский, Italiano, 日本語***

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) class should do what you want.

`getCountry()` will give you a country code, for which you can obtain the name via `getDisplayName()`.

Comment: How can I get String *Русский* from its code *ru* programmatically?

Comment: Read the docs for the Locale class, everything is explained there.